# How to get values from `ForeignKeyField` using peewee in join query?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, peewee

I have models like this (`peewee 2.10`):

```
class LegalAct(Model):
    start_date = DateField()
    expiration_date = DateField()

class SomeModel(Model):
    name = CharField()
    legal_act = ForeignKeyField(LegalAct)

class OtherModel(Model):
    name = Charfield()
    some_model = ForeignKeyField(SomeModel) 
    starting_legal_act = ForeignKeyField(LegalAct)
    closing_legal_act = ForeignKeyField(LegalAct)

class ExtraModel(Model):
    value = IntegerField()
    other_model = ForeignKeyField(OtherModel) 
    starting_legal_act = ForeignKeyField(LegalAct)
    closing_legal_act = ForeignKeyField(LegalAct)
```

Given list of `SomeModle.id`s and a `date` (to filter `LegalAct`) I want to get following data:

```
SomeModel.name
OtherModel.name
OtherModel.starting_legal_act.start_date
ExtraModel.starting_legal_act.start_date
ExtraModel.value
```

The issue is that I'm can't figure out how to traverse to `OtherModel.starting_legal_act.start_date` and `ExtraModel.starting_legal_act.start_date` - I only able to get `id` of the corresponding models and fetch the data in consequence queries.

My current code is like this:

```
other_model_legal_act = get_other_legal_act(date)  # a query
extra_model_legal_act = get_extra_legal_act(date)  # a query

data = OtherModel.select(
    SomeModel.name
    OtherModel.name
    OtherModel.starting_legal_act.alias('date_1')  # I get `id`, but want date
    ExtraModel.starting_legal_act.alias('date_2')  # I get `id`, but want date
    ExtraModel.value
).join(SomeModel).switch(OtherModel).join(ExtraModel).where(
    (OtherModel.legal_act == other_model_legal_act) &
    (ExtraModel.legal_act == extra_model_legal_act) &
    (SomeModel.id.in_(id_list))

)
```

I need to replace these lines with code that will return actual dates instead of record ids:

```
OtherModel.starting_legal_act.alias('date_1')  # I get `id`, but want date
ExtraModel.starting_legal_act.alias('date_2')  # I get `id`, but want date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want model aliases to reference the LegalAct multiple times:

```
LegalAct1 = LegalAct.alias()
LegalAct2 = LegalAct.alias()

data = OtherModel.select(
    SomeModel.name
    OtherModel.name
    LegalAct1.start_date.alias('date_1'),
    LegalAct2.start_date.alias('date_2'),
    OtherModel.starting_legal_act.alias('date_1')  # I get `id`, but want date
    ExtraModel.starting_legal_act.alias('date_2')  # I get `id`, but want date
    ExtraModel.value
)
.join(LegalAct1, on=(OtherModel.starting_legal_act == LegalAct.id))
.switch(OtherModel)
#
```

etc.

In the future...please try to make your models easier to reason about. "SomeModel" and "OtherModel" are absolutely useless.